# How to use access token that was saved as httpOnly cookie in authentication header?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, stormpath, express-stormpath

upon authentication stormpath express sets access token as httpOnly cookie in browser but how can I get the access token from the cookie to put it in authorization header as `Authorization: Bearer ey..access_token`? The token worked when I manually did the request using curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) library uses http-only cookies by default, when you post to the `/login` route, as they are more secure (by preventing access from the JavaScript environment, they cannot be stolen by XSS attacks).

If you need to access the tokens from the JavaScript environment, you should make a post to the `/oauth/token` endpoint, and you will receive the tokens in the HTTP response body.

This workflow is described here:

https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/authentication.html#oauth2-password-grant

Comment: I think I got it thanks! I noticed I should have used authenticationRequired or loginRequired to be able to utilize the cookie since apiAuthenticationRequired does not expect the access token in the cookie. I guess apiAuthenticationRequired is non-browser client authentication like mobile.